# How can I explicitly specify the size of the files to be split or the number of files?

Tags: amazon-athena

- Situation:
  If only specify the partition clause, it will be divided into multiple files. The size of one file is less than 1MB (~ 40 files).
- What  I am thinking of:
  I want to explicitly specify the size of the files to be split or the number of files when registering data with CTAS or INSERT INTO.

I have read this article: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/set-file-number-size-ctas-athena/

- Problem:
  Using bucketing method (like said in above article ) can help me specify the number of file or file size. However, it also said that "Note: The INSERT INTO statement isn't supported on bucketed tables". I would like to register data daily with Athena's INSERT INTO in the data mart.

what is the best way to build a partitioned data mart without compromising search efficiency? Is it best to register the data with Glue and save it as one file?

Comment: this might answer you https://stackoverflow.com/a/71905139/2096986