# Is there any other ways that I can specify output file size or number of output files using Athena except for "Bucketing"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I understand that I can set the number or size of files using "Bucketing" method (Refer to this guide: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/set-file-number-size-ctas-athena/ )

I also known that I can set the number of output file by using Glue job repartition. However, what I want to confirm is that:
Am I right if I understand that Bucketing is the only way so that the number of output file can be set if I use Athena? Is there any other methods?

Comment: I think that's the only method. What are you wanting to achieve -- more files, or less files? What is your motive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have search for many sources in the Internet and confirm with AWS Support team that Bucketing is the only  way to control the number of output files.

Thank you guys for your help!

Answer (score 3):

There are currently no other methods to control the number of output files of a CTAS operation.